# Mix several classes in the same file in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to manage several exceptions types. Each exception is just a defined classs, no more.

So, instead of having 5 files with empty class definition, I would like to group all exception of the same type in the same file.

Like that:

```
File: InvitationException.php

<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

class InvitationExpiredException extends \Exception
{


}
class InvitationNeededException extends \Exception
{


}
class InvitationNotActiveException extends \Exception
{


}
```

But in my code, when I try to throw a new exception:

```
if (is_null($invite)) throw new  App\Exceptions\InvitationNeededException();
```

I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Exceptions\InvitationNeededException' not found
```

Why is it happening???

EDIT: Duplicated, but the real duplicated is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033625/is-it-possible-use-multiple-classes-under-the-same-namespace-in-the-same-file) provided by xdevnull:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033625/is-it-possible-use-multiple-classes-under-the-same-namespace-in-the-same-file

Comment: Load it as independent file

Comment: yep, sorry, I didn't see it! Deleting ! Tx for your help!