# laravel 5 Added external Class not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have a php lib which is a set of functions,Here it is

```
<?php

# Copyright (c) 2010-2011 Arnaud Renevier, Inc, published under the modified BSD
# license.

namespace App\Gislib;
abstract class CustomException extends \Exception {
    protected $message;
    public function __toString() {
        return get_class($this) . " {$this->message} in {$this->file}({$this->line})\n{$this->getTraceAsString()}";
    }
}

class Unimplemented extends CustomException {
    public function __construct($message) {
        $this->message = "unimplemented $message";
    }
}

class UnimplementedMethod extends Unimplemented {
    public function __construct($method, $class) {
        $this->message = "method {$this->class}::{$this->method}";
    }
}

class InvalidText extends CustomException {
    public function __construct($decoder_name, $text = "") {
        $this->message =  "invalid text for decoder " . $decoder_name . ($text ? (": " . $text) : "");
    }
}

class InvalidFeature extends CustomException {
    public function __construct($decoder_name, $text = "") {
        $this->message =  "invalid feature for decoder $decoder_name" . ($text ? ": $text" : "");
    }
}

abstract class OutOfRangeCoord extends CustomException {
    private $coord;
    public $type;

    public function __construct($coord) {
        $this->message = "invalid {$this->type}: $coord";
    }
}
class OutOfRangeLon extends outOfRangeCoord {
    public $type = "longitude";
}
class OutOfRangeLat extends outOfRangeCoord {
    public $type = "latitude";
}

class UnavailableResource extends CustomException {
    public function __construct($ressource) {
        $this->message = "unavailable ressource: $ressource";
    }
}

interface iDecoder {
    /*
     * @param string $text
     * @return Geometry
     */
    static public function geomFromText($text);
}

abstract class Decoder implements iDecoder {
    static public function geomFromText($text) {
        throw new UnimplementedMethod(__FUNCTION__, get_called_class());
    }
}

interface iGeometry {
    /*
     * @return string
     */
    public function toGeoJSON();

    /*
     * @return string
     */
    public function toKML();

    /*
     * @return string
     */
    public function toWKT();

    /*
     * @param mode: trkseg, rte or wpt
     * @return string
     */
    public function toGPX($mode = null);

    /*
     * @param Geometry $geom
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function equals(Geometry $geom);
}

abstract class Geometry implements iGeometry {
    const name = "";

    public function toGeoJSON() {
        throw new UnimplementedMethod(__FUNCTION__, get_called_class());
    }

    public function toKML() {
        throw new UnimplementedMethod(__FUNCTION__, get_called_class());
    }

    public function toGPX($mode = null) {
        throw new UnimplementedMethod(__FUNCTION__, get_called_class());
    }

    public function toWKT() {
        throw new UnimplementedMethod(__FUNCTION__, get_called_class());
    }

    public function equals(Geometry $geom) {
        throw new UnimplementedMethod(__FUNCTION__, get_called_class());
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->toWKT();
    }
}

class GeoJSON extends Decoder {

    static public function geomFromText($text) {
        $ltext = strtolower($text);
        $obj = json_decode($ltext);
        if (is_null ($obj)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__, $text);
        }

        try {
            $geom = static::_geomFromJson($obj);
        } catch(InvalidText $e) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__, $text);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }

        return $geom;
    }

    static protected function _geomFromJson($json) {
        if (property_exists ($json, "geometry") and is_object($json->geometry)) {
            return static::_geomFromJson($json->geometry);
        }

        if (!property_exists ($json, "type") or !is_string($json->type)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        }

        foreach (array("Point", "MultiPoint", "LineString", "MultiLinestring", "LinearRing",
                       "Polygon", "MultiPolygon", "GeometryCollection") as $json_type) {
            if (strtolower($json_type) == $json->type) {
                $type = $json_type;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isset($type)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        }

        try {
            $components = call_user_func(array('static', 'parse'.$type), $json);
        } catch(InvalidText $e) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }

        $constructor = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $type;
        return new $constructor($components);
    }

   static protected function parsePoint($json) {
        if (!property_exists ($json, "coordinates") or !is_array($json->coordinates)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        }
        return $json->coordinates;
    }

    static protected function parseMultiPoint($json) {
        if (!property_exists ($json, "coordinates") or !is_array($json->coordinates)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        }
        return array_map(function($coords) {
            return new Point($coords);
        }, $json->coordinates);
    }

    static protected function parseLineString($json) {
        return static::parseMultiPoint($json);
    }

    static protected function parseMultiLineString($json) {
        $components = array();
        if (!property_exists ($json, "coordinates") or !is_array($json->coordinates)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        }
        foreach ($json->coordinates as $coordinates) {
            $linecomp = array();
            foreach ($coordinates as $coordinates) {
                $linecomp[] = new Point($coordinates);
            }
            $components[] = new LineString($linecomp);
        }
        return $components;
    }

    static protected function parseLinearRing($json) {
        return static::parseMultiPoint($json);
    }

    static protected function parsePolygon($json) {
        $components = array();
        if (!property_exists ($json, "coordinates") or !is_array($json->coordinates)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        }
        foreach ($json->coordinates as $coordinates) {
            $ringcomp = array();
            foreach ($coordinates as $coordinates) {
                $ringcomp[] = new Point($coordinates);
            }
            $components[] = new LinearRing($ringcomp);
        }
        return $components;
    }

    static protected function parseMultiPolygon($json) {
        $components = array();
        if (!property_exists ($json, "coordinates") or !is_array($json->coordinates)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        }
        foreach ($json->coordinates as $coordinates) {
            $polycomp = array();
            foreach ($coordinates as $coordinates) {
                $ringcomp = array();
                foreach ($coordinates as $coordinates) {
                    $ringcomp[] = new Point($coordinates);
                }
                $polycomp[] = new LinearRing($ringcomp);
            }
            $components[] = new Polygon($polycomp);
        }
        return $components;
    }

    static protected function parseGeometryCollection($json) {
        if (!property_exists ($json, "geometries") or !is_array($json->geometries)) {
            throw new InvalidText(__CLASS__);
        }
        $components = array();
        foreach ($json->geometries as $geometry) {
            $components[] = static::_geomFromJson($geometry);
        }

        return $components;
    }

}}
```

I have placed it in `App\Gislib\Gislib.php`
and in my controller I have added its using as `use App\Gislib\GeoJSON;` but when I try to load its class `$decoder =new \App\Gislib\GeoJSON();` it says `Class 'App\Gislib\GeoJSON' not found` where is my mistake?Is it related to extended types or namespaces? I know there are some other methods to call these classes but I just can load them using namespaces
thanks

Comment: did you add the namespace declaration on top of the file ?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild yes, I just edited my question,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each class or interface needs to be in its own file, with the file name matching the class name.

For example, in `app/Gislib/Unimplemented.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Gislib;

class Unimplemented extends CustomException {
    public function __construct($message) {
        $this->message = "unimplemented $message";
    }
}
```

and then in `app/Gislib/iDecoder.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Gislib;

interface iDecoder {
    /*
     * @param string $text
     * @return Geometry
     */
    static public function geomFromText($text);
}
```

This is due to Laravel following [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standards.

If you still get the error after splitting the file up, try running `composer dump`.

Comment: You don't neccessarily have to create single files for every class. In this case you could just add it to the files array in the composer.json's autoload section.

Comment: If you want to following PSR-4, which is used by the whole of Laravel, then you should.

Comment: Sure nothing wrong about this. Just wanted to point out an alternative. For an external library bundled in one file this 'files' approach is a case I would consider it is not tooo bad (especially if the file is really big ). For own implementations PSR-4 is a must of course.

Answer (score 2):

With PSR-4 autoloading it is required that the class name matches the file name. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033779 .

But what you can do is to modify your composer.json file like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files" : [
      "app/Gislib/Gislib.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Add as section "files" and provide the path to your lib. ( I think you have to do composer dump-autoload after that. Now it should work.